Hook into 3rd Party Wordpress Plugin Via Cron
I want to trigger a hook in 3rd party wordpress plugin via an external cron. I have the cron part figured out but can't for the life of me figure out how to create my own action to trigger the plugin's hook. The thing that is throwing me for a loop is that the external class seems to call another class in it. ($feed_cache = new \CustomFacebookFeed\CFF_Cache( $feed_id )) an I think this is important because I need to define the feed id as 11. I know the code I have is completely wrong because I have no clue what I am doing. The includes I have are the path's to the individual class files.
My code:
<?php function myCFFclearFeed(){
    require_once '/var/www/wp-content/plugins/custom-facebook-feed-pro/inc/Builder/CFF_Feed_Saver_Manager.php';
    require_once '/var/www/wp-content/plugins/custom-facebook-feed-pro/inc/CFF_Cache.php';
    $clear_feed_now = new CFF_Feed_Saver_Manager();
    $clear_feed_now->clear_single_feed_cache($feed_cache);
    $feed_cache = new \CustomFacebookFeed\CFF_Cache( $feed_id='11' );
    $feed_cache->clear( 'all' );
            $feed_cache->clear( 'posts' );
}
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_run_cff_clear_feed', 'myCFFclearFeed' );?>

The Plugin Action Hook:
...
...
The Plugin Class:
<?php 
/**
 * Used in an AJAX call to delete a feed cache from the Database
 * $_POST data.
 */
class CFF_Feed_Saver_Manager {
 
 
 public static function clear_single_feed_cache() {
    check_ajax_referer( 'cff-admin' , 'nonce');

    $cap = current_user_can( 'manage_custom_facebook_feed_options' ) ? 'manage_custom_facebook_feed_options' : 'manage_options';
    $cap = apply_filters( 'cff_settings_pages_capability', $cap );
    if ( ! current_user_can( $cap ) ) {
        wp_send_json_error(); // This auto-dies.
    }
    $feed_id = sanitize_text_field( wp_unslash( $_POST['feedID'] ) );

    if ( $feed_id === 'legacy' ) {
        \CustomFacebookFeed\CFF_Cache::clear_legacy();
    } else {
        if ( \CustomFacebookFeed\CFF_FB_Settings::check_active_extension( 'multifeed' ) ) {
            \CustomFacebookFeed\CFF_Cache::clear_legacy();
        }
         
        $feed_cache = new \CustomFacebookFeed\CFF_Cache( $feed_id );

        $feed_cache->clear( 'all' );
        $feed_cache->clear( 'posts' );
    }

    CFF_Feed_Saver_Manager::feed_customizer_fly_preview();
    wp_die();

}} ?>


Note that this isn't going to work because if you take a closer look at the plugin's code it does some checks to make sure that the clear_single_feed_cache() function is being called via AJAX (see the check_ajax_referer(...) bit?), and your cronjob will fail that check. It also checks that the request is coming from a logged-in user, and since the request is coming from a cronjob task... In short, you'll need a different solution .

If you don't need the checks for whether this is triggered by a user who has the rights to do so, then I think you basically just need to recreate the if ( $feed_id === 'legacy' ) {...} else {...} block somewhere else. (The part before that only does the access checks, and the feed_customizer_fly_preview probably doesn't do anything, that you would need in this context either.) Instead of adding this as an AJAX action, set it up as a custom Rest API endpoint.

The problem is that the Wordpress Cron is not firing correctly. There is a Clear Cache function in the cron. Maybe I can fire the Clear Cache function in the cron? Could I set up something to trigger the clear cache in that? .There's no class it belongs to. it's a free function. Here's the Cron code. ...<?php //Cron job to clear transients
add_action('cff_cron_job', 'cff_cron_clear_cache');
function cff_cron_clear_cache() {
//Delete all transients unless it's using background caching
if( get_option('cff_caching_type') != 'background' ) cff_delete_cache();
}
